# Mapping of Login Credentials with Public IP

Tags: .net, ipv4

I have built a **.NET** web application which is used to resolve customers query 
Application is getting used by branch employees which are situated across PAN India location.
Average active users count always vary in between **1300 – 1400**.
In earlier stage ,Application was available on **Internet** to users but due to some security reasons I have shifted it to **Intranet**.
Users have their own dedicated user ID and password to login into application but we came across few instances where users had started sharing their credentials to access the application.
In order to track password sharing activities I have implemented various application patches but didn’t achieve complete control on it.

**Problem Statement** : Is there any way to map login credential of user with it private IP ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a single logon trick and log the logged in ip address to track the users log.

You can also specify that if their ip address is not correct, it shouldn't log in to the system